# IE7 loading cursor flickers and makes page slow to respond

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem where moving the cursor and clicking in text fields causes the page to show a wait cursor and also makes the page very unresponsive.

[image: IE7 wait cursor problem]

See [this video](http://youtu.be/tXOZCN97Cg0) for an example of it happening.

It only happens in *IE7*.

I've tried checking where I think it might be sending off ajax requests (thought this could be changing the cursor).

I've checked where I think multiple events may be firing simultaneously and tried commenting it out.

**Has anyone seen anything similar happen and can point me in the right direction?**

**What is IE7's criteria for displaying the wait cursor?**

Comment: if you try to replicate your CSS and the form on jsFiddle, does it do the same thing?

Comment: Unfortunately I've been unable to replicate this, which makes it very difficult to find out what's going wrong. I'm hoping someone has seen something similar and can give me a few pointers.

Comment: What is firing when you are clicking the input? Are their events attached to it. [also sucks to be you supporting IE7!] Remove the events that are attach and add them back one by one and figure out what is causing it.

Comment: is there any javascript that interacts with the form? JS is supper slow in IE7 so that can easily mess it up.

Comment: Consider dropping IE7 support. It is obsolete and has a negligible market share.

Comment: @MaratTanalin unless your user base has high IE7 support and some actually do.

Comment: There is a lot of JavaScript on the page but I think there are only "blur" events attached to the inputs, so I can't figure out why the cursor flickers even on mouse move. But the JavaScript is quite heavy on the page so I guess it doesn't help with IE7 being slow to process JavaScript. I really do hate having to support it but it's necessary :(

Comment: @MaratTanalin This user base is quite high on IE7, it's a business to business company, and a lot of businesses seem to have very old versions of IE, I'm guessing something to do with their security policies.

Comment: @Ally Do you use IE expressions (JS as a CSS property value) or HTC components (JS as *.htc files)?

Comment: @MaratTanalin That's a good idea thanks but it doesn't look as if any are in use.

Comment: Should a wait cursor be shown if JavaScript is executing? That will probably narrow it down between Ajax requests or JavaScript events. I tried running IE's profiler under developer tools but could not see any ajax requests being sent, so I mentally excluded that possibility (although I don't have much faith in Internet Explorer to assume it's reporting the right information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I narrowed down the issue. After eliminating code bit by bit I deduced the problem isn't caused by JavaScript at all, it's a css issue.

The exact line of css is

```
overflow-y: auto
```

I don't know exactly the circumstances to reproduce it. But for a bit of info that might help others... The container the css is applied to is positioned absolutely. It has a fixed size (which also seems to be changed in JavaScript) and width. It's parent container is a `div` with `display:block;`.

Curiously if you scroll to the bottom of the container and back up it seems to fix the flickering bug.

Comment: @kamaci Honestly can't remember sorry, I most likely removed that line entirely.