# Disable Mouse Cursor Progress

Tags: jquery, css, mouse-cursor

When user makes any operation I do not want to see mouse courser progress/loading icon. I mean I want to disable mouse cursor loading at my page.

I can catch the mouse cursor change and check whether it is progress or not. If it is progress I can change it to any other cursor.

How can I do that?

**PS 1:** Browser triggers that event and even when I change the cursor type it get automatically progress.

**PS 2:** Check this question to understand probable cause of my problem: [IE7 loading cursor flickers and makes page slow to respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593687/ie7-loading-cursor-flickers-and-makes-page-slow-to-respond)

**PS 3:** I use jQuery 1.6.2 and Internet Explorer 9

Answer (score 0):

Browse css and find `cursor: wait;` or find in  IE inspector which elements browser is adding/styling by cursor attribute with value wait. Then try to overlap.

[Getting the browser cursor from "wait" to "auto" without the user moving the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718415/getting-the-browser-cursor-from-wait-to-auto-without-the-user-moving-the-mou)